# Clone Element that behave as unique elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating clones with hidden div, I've created a function to show the hidden div, but the function currently only affects the original element. How do I create a function that affects individual clones?

I think I have to change each id in each loop, but I do not know if I'm getting this change, and I still do not know, how will I pass the id of the div that will be affected, as a parameter to function

```js
father = document.getElementById('father')
child = document.getElementById('child')

function showDescription(id) {
  const divHidden = document.getElementById("idElement")
  divHidden.classList.toggle('hide');
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var newElement = child.cloneNode(true);
  newElement.id = "idElement" + i;
  father.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

```html
<div id="father">
  <div id="child">
    <div class="row" Onclick="showDescription()">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <h3>Bolsonaro ainda no Hospital têm recaida e está com pneumonia</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Div Occult -->
    <div id="idElement" class="hide col-md-12">
      <p>O presidente Jair Bolsonaro (PSL) teve episódio isolado zde febre nesta quarta-feira </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wish that by clicking on a cloned div, it shows the div hidden only in the corresponding element

Comment: from Onclick="showDescription()" to Onclick="showDescription(this)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to add event listener for each `newElement` as they are created.
I used a `<template>` tag as it seems more appropriate for stamping markups.

```html
<div id="father"></div>
<template id="child-template">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <h3>Bolsonaro ainda no Hospital têm recaida e está com pneumonia</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Div Occult -->
    <div class="hide col-md-12 description">
      <p>O presidente Jair Bolsonaro (PSL) teve episódio isolado zde febre nesta quarta-feira </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  const father = document.getElementById('father');
  const childTemplate = document.getElementById('child-template');

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // clone the template and get the first child in the template tag (.child)
    const newElement = childTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).children[0];
    // add event listener to div with `row` class to
    // toggle the div with `description` class
    newElement.querySelector('.row').addEventListener('click',
      () => newElement.querySelector('.description').classList.toggle('hide')
    );
    father.appendChild(newElement);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code. which you will `click`  it will call `showDescription` and in that it will toggle class of `<div class="row">`. In `css` I use `.hide+div` which will select the next sibling div which is `<div id="idElement" class="hide col-md-12">` and will hide/show in `click`

```js
father = document.getElementById('father')
child = document.getElementById('child')

function showDescription(elm) {
  elm.classList.toggle('hide');
  //divHidden.classList.toggle('hide');
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var newElement = child.cloneNode(true);
  newElement.id = "idElement" + i;
  father.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

```css
.hide+div{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="father">
  <div id="child">
    <div class="row" Onclick="showDescription(this)">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <h3>Bolsonaro ainda no Hospital têm recaida e está com pneumonia</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Div Occult -->
    <div id="idElement" class="hide col-md-12">
      <p>O presidente Jair Bolsonaro (PSL) teve episódio isolado zde febre nesta quarta-feira </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `showDescription(this)` to pass on the selected element.

Se the example code, i only made changes to `showDescription` and html `Onclick="showDescription(this)"`

```js
father = document.getElementById('father')
child = document.getElementById('child')
function showDescription(el) {
  const divHidden = el.parentNode.querySelectorAll("#idElement")[0]
  divHidden.classList.toggle('hide');
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var newElement = child.cloneNode(true);
  newElement.id = "idElement" + i;
  father.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

```css
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="father">
  <div id="child">
    <div class="row" Onclick="showDescription(this)">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <h3>Bolsonaro ainda no Hospital têm recaida e está com pneumonia</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Div Occult -->
    <div id="idElement" class="hide col-md-12">
      <p>O presidente Jair Bolsonaro (PSL) teve episódio isolado zde febre nesta quarta-feira </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the **this** keyword to your inline event handler you can use [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) instead of getElementById. In this way your function is:

```
function showDescription(ele) {
  ele.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```js
father = document.getElementById('father')
child = document.getElementById('child')


function showDescription(ele) {
    ele.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide');
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var newElement = child.cloneNode(true);
    newElement.id = "idElement" + i;
    father.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="father">
    <div id="child">
        <div class="row" Onclick="showDescription(this)">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <h3>Bolsonaro ainda no Hospital têm recaida e está com pneumonia</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Div Occult -->
        <div id="idElement" class="hide col-md-12">
            <p>O presidente Jair Bolsonaro (PSL) teve episódio isolado zde febre nesta quarta-feira </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```